# SQL Query - Finding records where value doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Take the below data as an example

Table a

```
  User      TokenStatus         
 -----      -----------   
  a         Valid
  a         Valid
  b         Deactivated
  b         Deactivated
  c         Valid
  c         Valid
  c         Suspended
  d         Deactivated
  d         Suspended
```

I would like to find all the users where they don't have a Token assigned to them with a status of 'Valid' i.e all users who have no Valid tokens (or all other statuses except valid)

So for the example above I would like the results (because users a and c have valid tokens)

Results

```
  User              
 -----      
  b                 
  d
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Hello, I'm using MSSQL

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct [User] from tableA where TokenStatus <> 'Valid'
except
select distinct [User] from tableA where TokenStatus = 'Valid'
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85341/1

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select distinct t1.user_name
from the_table t1
where not exists (select 42
                  from the_table t2
                  where t2.user_name = t1.user_name
                    and t2.tokenStatus = 'Valid');
```

(Note that I used `user_name` as the column because `user` is a reserved word in nearly every database which would required special handling if  used as a column name)

Comment: This seems to have done the trick - many thanks for this! I didn't actually have both columns in the same table so created a temp table and used your query on this. Would it be possible to do this in a single query using joins rather than a temp table? (I'm very new to SQL programming so please bear with me!)

The UserID and TokenStatus are in two different tables so I need to join them first before applying the query above.

Comment: @user3421229: that **is** a single query and it's not using a "temp table. You need to supply the full definition of the tables if you want complete answers

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.[User]
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
  SELECT 1 FROM YourTable t2 WHERE t2.TokenStatus = 'Valid' And t1.[User] = t2.[User] 
)
```

SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6aa092/4